# Get integer value from key list java

Tags: java, parsing, key, arrays

I have a json file like following:

```
[
    {
        "100": "2"
    },
    {
        "50": "5"
    },
    {
        "30": "3"
    },
    {
        "10": "8"
    },
    {
        "5": "4"
    }
]
```

After parsing it I was able to get the keys:

```
public static void main(String[] args, int value)
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = 
                        (JSONArray) parser.parse(
                                new FileReader("/Users/.../Documents/workspace/testCase/bin/test.json"));

                int remaining = value;
                for (int n = 0 ; n < jsonArray.size(); n++)
                {
                    JSONObject note = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(n);
                    Set keys = note.keySet();
                    int result = Math.floor(remaining/keys);
                    }

            }
    }
```

how can I extract keys as an integer from keys set so that I can use `int numOfChange = Math.floor(remaining/keys);` operation?

Comment: I think you mean how to change string to integer: if its the case you can simply do : Integer.parseInt(key);

Comment: I want to change Set to Integer. in the above example I want to change "keys" to Integer.I used parseInt but I got "The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Set)" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` method requires String as parameter, since you have a set you need to iterate through the elements. for example something like:

```
for(String s : keys){
  System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

**NOTE** below implementation is based on a question in the comments:

**Question**: Given a Set as parameter return a Set by converting String to Integer

```
public Set<Intege> StringSetToIntegerSet(Set<String> input) throws Exception{
   Set<Integer> output=new HashSet<Integer>();
   for(String s : input){
      output.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
   }
   return output;
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to return "Integer.parseInt(s)" value form this iteration?

Comment: @NIna just make a method that takes a set<String> as parameter and returns a Set<Integer>.

Comment: can you help me with the implementation? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure, whether this is what you mean but by the way I understand,

As you get a string from the file, in order to treat them as integers, you have to parse them for example

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(string);
```

If you want to keep the same lining, you could probably read both strings of a line, saving them in a HashMap, as in the first string parsed saved as the key and the second as the value